# Difference between nonconformity and inconformity?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, word-meaning, word-difference

I met following sentence while reading a passage:

> avoided some inconformities

However, I found that computer auto-check show a red line under `inconformities` which means it is wrong. However I check an online dictionary for [inconformity](http://dict.youdao.com/search?q=inconformity). It is not a wrong-spelling word. If the word is spelled correctly, what wrong with this phrase. Why do auto-check system change it to `nonconformity`

Comment: I think it should be hyphenated like in-conformities. However, not all the errors triggered by spell-checkers are really important.

Comment: Because *inconformity* is a **very** rare word and probably not in your spell-checker's dictionary. Software grammar- and spelling-checkers cannot be trusted.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, I see. As a English learner, I sometimes rely on spell-checker to check some spell mistake. I know it is not reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconformity), instead of giving a definition of "inconformity", just gives a link to the word "nonconformity". This suggests that "inconformity" exists, but that "nonconformity" is the better choice.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inconformity,%20nonconformity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,inconformity;,c0;.t1;,nonconformity;,c0) shows that "nonconformity" is used much oftener than "inconformity".